# automatically import data from CSV to excel/calc sheet

Tags: excel, csv, openoffice-calc, vba

I have here 12 CSV source file (just numbers separated with semicolon).

I need on one action/click take this data and import it to excel/calc to 12 sheets (1 sheet for 1 csv source).

Any Idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

you can do it with Excel vba:

- create a **new workbook** (or use the current one depending on your needs)
- ask the user to **select several csv files** (if they are on the same folder, else, you can ask the user if he still have some more to import) >> [doc here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelsDialogBoxes.htm)
- copy or **move the imported worksheet** to the new or current workbook (>> [Excel 2003 VBA: Move a sheet into a new workbook that is referenced by a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332941/excel-2003-vba-move-a-sheet-into-a-new-workbook-that-is-referenced-by-a-variable))

Please let us know if you encounter some trouble building your procedure

Answer (score 1):

By using the code in [this post](http://www.zerrtech.com/content/excel-vba-open-csv-file-and-import) combined with a loop in which you step through the filenames (which you could keep in an array of string) and vary the `.Destination` with the sheets in the workbook(you can step through them by making as many new sheets as you need in the workbook and then going from `Sheets(1)` through `Sheets(N)`, where N is the number of sheets.